# testing browser media events with protractor

Tags: javascript, mocking, protractor

I'm trying to create some front-end tests for a site which accesses the local camera.

Is it possible to mock accepting or denying the local camera in a protractor test? 
I've already got my unit tests which can check the state of the app which changes depending on if the camera has been accepted or not, but I am unable to check that the correct UI is displayed based on the status of camera permission.

Is mocking getUserMedia the best way to manage that? Or is there another way?

Note: I am not using angular, I'm using mercury.js